# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MessagesController#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner to RoR, I am trying to add a checkbox feature(select multiple checkboxes of data records and delete it) to the tables in my application. While I select a checkbox and click the delete button I got an error(as said in the title).

Here is my controller file:

```
def destroy
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  @message.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to messages_url, notice: 'Message was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_message
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:content)
end
```

Here is my index.html file:

```
<h1>Messages</h1>
<%= form_tag messages_path, method: :delete do %>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <% @messages.each do |message| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "message_ids[]", message.id%></td>
        <td><%= message.content %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', message %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message) %></td>
        <!-- <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', message, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td> -->
      </tr>
    <% end %> 
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<%= button_to "Delete", message_path(@messages),method: :delete%>
</br>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= link_to  'New Message', new_message_path %> 
</br>
```

here is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :messages do
    collection {delete :destroy}    
  end
  root to: "messages#index"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Error Shown:

> Couldn't find Message with 'id'=
>
> Extracted source (around line #69): 67 68 69 70 71 72
>
> ```
> # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
> def set_message
>   @message = Message.find(params[:id])
> end
>
> # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
> ```
>
> Please help me to identify my mistake....

Comment: Can you confirm if the id is being passed correctly ? what does your `params` contain?

Comment: pass specific id on this link not all ids 
<%= button_to "Delete", message_path(@messages),method: :delete%>
<%= button_to "Delete", message_path(@message.id),method: :delete%> so delete specific record..

Comment: @ChaudharyPrakash I pass specific id on this delete link, while i run the server it shows   NoMethodError in Messages#index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your Delete button, it should be like this.

```
<h1>Messages</h1>
<%= form_tag messages_path, method: :delete do %>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <% @messages.each do |message| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "message_ids[]", message.id%></td>
        <td><%= message.content %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', message %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message) %></td>
        <!-- <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', message, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td> -->
      </tr>
    <% end %> 
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<%#= button_to "Delete", message_path(@messages),method: :delete%>
<%= submit_tag :Delete,class: 'btn' %>

</br>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= link_to  'New Message', new_message_path %> 
</br>
```

After submitting form you will get array of message id at controller in `params[:message_ids]`

so at destroy action: -

```
def destroy
      #@message = Message.find(params[:id])
      @messages = Message.where(id: params[:message_ids])
      #@messages.destroy
      @messages.destroy_all
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to messages_url, notice: 'Message was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end
```

Note: - if you are using before action to for destroy method then don't use before_action callbacks for destroy method;

```
before_action :set_message, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
```

Comment: Even I change my code as u said I got a same error, The error has been show the set_message method in my controller under the private class.

Comment: @Priya i understand your confusion , did you notice last line notes at my answer, as i sad are you using call backs at top of your controller like `before_action` or `before_filter`?

Comment: Thanks @Gabbar  but after I remove destroy method from `before_action`     I got a error       **NoMethodError in MessagesController#destroy
undefined method `destroy_all' for #<Array:0x007f242e5d49c8>**

Comment: @Priya okay lets use only `destroy` instead of `destroy_all` hopefully this should work .:)

Comment: Sorry I tried it before u say but I got same error ** NoMethodError in MessagesController#destroy
undefined method `destroy' for #<Array:0x00000003c017e8>**

Comment: @Priya yep sorry it was my mistake, i figured out now. here try this: -
`@messages = Message.where(id: params[:message_ids])` and `@messages.destroy_all` hopefully it should work.

Comment: @Priya basically `where` returns array of `active records` so destroy_all will work .  previously find returns only array of records so it was rerunning error.

Comment: @Priya feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you, and let me know for further guidance. thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works fine. Sorry for the late reply I was in meeting, Once again Thanks a lot :-) @Gabbar

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to select a model with an array of ids. You would want to do something like  Message.where(:id => params[:ids]).destroy_all. Where params[:ids] = [1,2,3,etc.].

Answer (score 0):

You can divide it into two method.

Create destroy_multiple in controller

```
def destroy_multiple
  @messages = Message.where(id: params[:message_ids])
  @messages.destroy_all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to messages_url, notice: 'Message was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Revised your routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :messages do
    collection { delete :destroy_multiple }    
  end
  root to: "messages#index"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Your html file.

```
<%= form_tag destroy_multiple_messages_path, method: :delete do %>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <% @messages.each do |message| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "message_ids[]", message.id%></td>
        <td><%= message.content %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', message %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', message, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %> 
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<%= button_to "Delete", message_path(@messages), method: :delete%>
</br>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= link_to  'New Message', new_message_path %> 
</br>
```

4. You don't need to change your `destroy` method

```
def destroy
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  @messages.destroy
  @messages.destroy_all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to messages_url, notice: 'Message was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Conclusion, you have two delete features. I hope this help you.